# javascript save multiple value in map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, object

[image]
i am facing an issue in javascript. i want to do push `name` into `array_value`. but `name` are not save in array `array_name.push(array_value)`

What should i do? Anyone help me?

**my code:**

```js
var agent_id;
var agent_name;
var array_value = [];
agents_array.map(agent => {
// console.log("agent);      //(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
// console.log("agent.id);   //5b6a838b-fd7c-4d75-a418-d83b7dbba6e5
if(agent.id == $("#agent-id").select2().val()){                
agent_id = agent.id
agent_name = agent.first_name +" "+ agent.last_name;
array_name.push(array_value);   //not working
}
})
```

console.log agent data

```
{groups: Array(0), first_name: "Ayaz",id: "5b6a838b-fd7c-4d75-a418-d83b7dbba6e5", last_name: "Mehmood", …}
{groups: Array(0), first_name: "Ghazanfar",id: "3c5ee1f8-f65c-4237-a117-d9d63f4d98f8", last_name: "Haq", …}
{groups: Array(0), first_name: "Mubeen",id: "ed2644ba-de49-4a5f-951c-71f9486c4b0c", last_name: "Ejaz", …}
```

Comment: where exactly do you define array_name here? and why are you pushing an empty array into it?

Comment: i added a photo console log [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12347245/talmacel-marian-silviu)

Answer (score 0):

array_name.push(array_value);   //not working

try

array_value.push(array_name);